# Code Refactoring Extract To a Method

Tags: java

Friends

I have below two overloaded methods which throw same ServiceException

```
private ModResponse updateNDelTerms(GlobalTermDeleteType item, boolean isGlobal)
    {
        StdTerm stdTerm = getTerm(item.getstdTermId());
        if (stdTerm == null || !getBuilder().getOwnerId().equals(stdTerm.getOwnerId()))
        {
            throw new ServiceException(GLOBAL_TERM_TO_DELETE_DOES_NOT_EXIST_MSG,
                    CANNOT_DELETE_GLOBAL_TERM, GLOBAL_TERM_DOES_NOT_EXIST);
        }

        if (stdTerm.isGlobal() && !isGlobal)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(
                    "Global Term can not be updated: incorrect URL.",
                    CANNOT_UPDATE_GLOBAL_TERM, INCORRECT_URL);
        }

        if (stdTerm.isLocked() != null && stdTerm.isLocked())
        {
            throw new ServiceException("Global Term can not be updated: stdTerm is locked.",
                    CANNOT_UPDATE_GLOBAL_TERM, TERM_LOCKED);
        }

        return updateNDel(item, stdTerm);
    }
```

Second method is

```
public ItemResponse<List<stdTermItemType>> copyTerm(
                                        BigInteger stdTermId, boolean isGlobal,
            boolean isFalse)
    {
        StdTerm stdTerm = getTerm(stdTermId);

        if (stdTerm == null || !getBuilder().getOwnerId().equals(stdTerm.getOwnerId()))
        {
            throw new ServiceException(GLOBAL_TERM_TO_DELETE_DOES_NOT_EXIST_MSG,
                    CANNOT_DELETE_GLOBAL_TERM, GLOBAL_TERM_DOES_NOT_EXIST);
        }

        if (stdTerm.isGlobal() && !isGlobal)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(
                    "Global Term can not be updated: incorrect URL.",
                    CANNOT_COPY_GLOBAL_TERM, INCORRECT_URL);
        }

        if (stdTerm.isLocked() != null && stdTerm.isLocked())
        {
            throw new ServiceException("Rate sheet term can not be updated: stdTerm is locked.",
                    CANNOT_COPY_GLOBAL_TERM, TERM_LOCKED);
        }
        return copyGlobleTerm(stdTerm, pasteTermObj, isFalse);
    }
```

I am thinking of refactoring these two methods and use Extract common code to a method ,
However due to difference in **CANNOT_COPY_GLOBAL_TERM** and **CANNOT_UPDATE_GLOBAL_TERM** which are unique to both the methods hence
**Im not able to achieve Extract to a Method refactoring .**
Please suggest .

Comment: assign CANNOT_COPY_GLOBAL_TERM and CANNOT_UPDATE_GLOBAL_TERM to a local variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private StdTerm retrieveStdTerm(BigInteger stdTermId, boolean isGlobal, String errorTerm)
{
    StdTerm stdTerm = getTerm(BigInteger stdTermId);
    if (stdTerm == null || !getBuilder().getOwnerId().equals(stdTerm.getOwnerId()))
    {
        throw new ServiceException(GLOBAL_TERM_TO_DELETE_DOES_NOT_EXIST_MSG,
                CANNOT_DELETE_GLOBAL_TERM, GLOBAL_TERM_DOES_NOT_EXIST);
    }
    if (stdTerm.isGlobal() && !isGlobal)
    {
        throw new ServiceException(
                "Global Term can not be updated: incorrect URL.",
                errorTerm, INCORRECT_URL);
    }
    if (stdTerm.isLocked() != null && stdTerm.isLocked())
    {
        throw new ServiceException("Global Term can not be updated: stdTerm is locked.",
                errorTerm, TERM_LOCKED);
    }
    return stdTerm;
}

private ModResponse updateNDelTerms(GlobalTermDeleteType item, boolean isGlobal)
{
    StdTerm stdTerm = retrieveStdTerm(item.getstdTermId(), isGlobal,
            CANNOT_DELETE_GLOBAL_TERM);
    return updateNDel(item, stdTerm);
}

public ItemResponse<List<stdTermItemType>> copyTerm(BigInteger stdTermId, boolean isGlobal,
        boolean isFalse)
{
    StdTerm stdTerm = retrieveStdTerm(stdTermId, isGlobal, CANNOT_COPY_GLOBAL_TERM);
    return copyGlobleTerm(stdTerm, pasteTermObj, isFalse);
}
```

Comment: excellent Joop Eggen. very helpful refactoring and I learnt something new from your code , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the things that are different into the extracted method.

You could also turn those methods into lambdas and pass them in as well if you're running on JDK 8.  Use a more functional style.

Comment: agree , However Im using Java 7 now :)  Thanks

Comment: Time to upgrade.  JDK 7 has passed the end of its support life.  Plan now.